# Access URL that 404'd in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to get the URL that returned a 404 status to display on my error page.

I have this in my web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And this controller set up

```
@Controller
public class HTTPErrorController {

@RequestMapping(value="/errors/404.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handle404(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("referer", request.getRequestURL());

        return "error404";
    }
}
```

That gives me the /error/404.html URL.

If I try to access the "referer" header from the HttpServletRequest:

```
request.getHeader("referer");
```

It's always null.

I would like to pass the URL through the model so I can display it on my error page.

So, for example, if I go to "http://www.example.com/garbage" in my application and that 404s, it will display the "error404" view, and I want "http://www.example.com/garbage" to be available on the view.

Comment: topher-which version of spring you are using?

Comment: I'm using spring 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/constant-values.html

static final java.lang.String ERROR_REQUEST_URI
The name of the request attribute that should be set by the container when custom error-handling servlet or JSP page is invoked. The value of the attribute is of type java.lang.String. See the chapter "Error Handling" in the Servlet Specification for details.
Since:
Servlet 3.0
See Also:
Constant Field Values